# Can Gstreamer support be enabled for precompiled OpenCV which does not have Gstreamer?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation, gstreamer, ubuntu-18.04

I have pre-compiled OpenCV 3.2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04 which currently does not have Gstreamer.

Is it possible to enable this by installing pre-compiled OpenCV binaries from apt like below or any other way than recompiling entire OpenCV. I'm trying to keep the system image minimal.

```sh
gstreamer1.0-opencv/bionic-updates 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64
  GStreamer OpenCV plugins

libgstreamer-opencv1.0-0/bionic-updates 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64
  GStreamer OpenCV libraries
```

Comment: no it is not possible. also 3.2.0 is far too old to be useful

Comment: Ok thanks, will compile it then